# Content-Security-Policy: Getting weird reports with frame-ancestors 'self'

Tags: content-security-policy, clickjacking

Right now, I maintain the Content-Security-Policy for https://www.lidl.de, which is:

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'; block-all-mixed-content; report-uri https://lidlcsp.report-uri.io/r/default/csp/enforce;
```

The part with frame-ancestors is to protect against clickjacking.

When going through the violation reports sent to report-uri.io, the number one is the following,

```
{
    "csp-report": {
        "blocked-uri": "",
        "document-uri": "https://www.lidl.de/",
        "original-policy": "frame-ancestors https://www.lidl.de; block-all-mixed-content; report-uri https://lidlcsp.report-uri.io/r/default/csp/enforce",
        "violated-directive": "frame-ancestors https://www.lidl.de"
    }
}
```

which is sent from Firefox (as report-uri.io shows). I'm puzzled on two things here:

1. Why is this report sent? I can't reproduce it.
2. Why is the "original policy" altered ('self' vs. https://www.lidl.de)? Does this make any difference?
3. (**EDIT**) Why is `https://www.lidl.de/` blocked in the following report? The csp explicitly allows iframes on the same site via `'self'`.

**EDIT:**
To make the third question a bit clearer I add another `csp-report`:

```
{
    "csp-report": {
        "document-uri": "https://www.lidl.de/",
        "effective-directive": "frame-ancestors",
        "original-policy": "frame-ancestors 'self'; block-all-mixed-content; report-uri https://lidlcsp.report-uri.io/r/default/csp/enforce;",
        "blocked-uri": "https://www.lidl.de/"
    }
}
```

If you can reproduce the CSP violation or can trigger other violations I would be happy to learn about them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is the "original policy" altered ('self' vs. https://www.lidl.de)? Does this make any difference?

`'self'` in the CSP actually stands for "same domain". It is just a placeholder, so this is evaluated by browsers to, in your case, `https://www.lidl.de`. That's exactly what you say the directive should do, it is just written in another way. So no, **it does not make a difference**.

> Why is this report sent? I can't reproduce it.

I am nearly sure that in 90% of these cases the answer is: browser add-ons. If you really cannot reproduce it with a clean profile and same browser/same site, it is very likely just a browser extension injecting respectively trying to inject some stuff. That is a very common source/trigger for CSP reports.

However, as it is the [`frame-ancestors` directive](https://content-security-policy.com/#directive) in your case, you may easily be able to reproduce it. Just create an iframe trying to embed your site:

```
<iframe height="500" width="500" src="https://www.lidl.de"></iframe>
```

That should fail, and trigger the CSP report. Because that is what clickjacking is about: Your site getting embedded in another site, in such a way the user does not see it and clicks on things, the user did not want to click on.

I know Report-URI has some filters to prevent such reports caused by browser add-ons, but they still cannot catch all of them.

---

BTW:

> The part with frame-ancestors is to protect against clickjacking.

It does, but you may actually (better, or, even better: additionally) use the header `X-Frame-Options` for that purpose. This header was [designed for that](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/x-frame-options), and also works with browsers, who do not support CSP (it is older, in any case). See the [security headers scan from the same author as Report-URI](https://securityheaders.io/?q=lidl.de&followRedirects=on) for more details. While you are at it, you may also have a look at the other security headers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added another csp report to clarify one question I still have. To me it looks like https://www.lidl.de is trying to load content from https://www.lidl.de but this should be allowed by `frame-ancestors 'self'`.

Comment: Please don't add new sub-questions via edits. If your question is answered, mark the answer and open a new question.

Comment: You are correct. Given your CSP, the site should allow embedding on itself. I tested this on the homepage using the mentioned iframe sample and the URL `https://www.lidl.de/somesite` (which, of course, 404s, but is displayed); Screen: https://i.imgur.com/fCQY2IF.png

Embeeding it on `https://www.test.de` did not work and was blocked by the CSP: https://i.imgur.com/nQkRRkU.png

So why you got this other strange CSP report is not clear to me. Maybe arcane add-on/browser combinations. At least the CSP works as expected in my tests.

Comment: BTW: On your site you also got this violation (triggered by 404 page, as it seems): `Content Security Policy: Unsichere Anfrage 'http://www.lidl.de/de/search?query=somesite&log=not_found' wird blockiert.` (2 times).